# GCC Plugin: Detecting target pointer size

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction

GCC compiles on several platforms and each of these platforms have a different native pointer size (e.g. 32-bit on x86, 64-bit on x64). And on 64-bit platforms, you can even pass it an mx32 flag to make it 'cross compile' to x86.

How would a GCC plugin detect the ***target*** (i.e. the platform GCC is generating code for) pointer size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was actually quite easy.
Here it is.

`pointerSizeInBits = TYPE_PRECISION(integer_ptr_type_node);`